# yii2 сохранение в базе загруженного изображения

Tags: php, yii2

Доброе время суток
вопрос такой, как привязать изображение к статье из формы.

Я воспользовался стандартным методом yii2;

Поле imageFile;
в базе, в это же таблице создал поле imageFile;

в контроллере у меня следующее

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
        if ($model->imageFile) {
            $model->upload();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
```

Метод загрузки - стандартный

```
 public function upload()
{

    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Изображения из формы отлично загружаются, но когда смотрю что приходит постом , в поле imageFile  sting 0

а мне нужно в базе привязать изображение которое загрузилось.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать, или где почитать, посмотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы реализовали загрузку файла, осталось реализовать сохранение в базу название этого файла. К примеру в базе у вас поле `image` в модели объявите просто публичное поле `imageFile`

```
class TableName extends ActiveRecord{
    public $imageFile;
    ...
```

В контроллере примерно следующая логика:

- загрузить $_POST данные в модель
- получить информацию о файле (`UploadedFile::getInstance()`)
- выполнить валидацию модели
- загрузить файл и добавить название файла в поле базы
- сохранить модель

Примерно:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
    if($this->validate()){
        if ($model->imageFile && $model->upload()) {
            $model->image = $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension;
        }
        if($this->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ага, я понял, а то у меня проблема была в получении имени , поскольку еще ламер) Сейчас перепишу немного, спасибо

Comment: сохраняется. Я пологаю дело в том, что данные которые сохраняются хранятся в  ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> , а $model->image на уровень выше

Comment: http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/17/0121/h_1485026272_2367890_893a54f30f.png

Comment: можете подсказать? буду признателен

Comment: @mydls1 в чем конкретно? все ведь сохраняется? из картинки ощущение что вы объявили image в модели просто, а не добавили ее в таблицу + прописали в rules